# UIBarButtonItem: how can I change the text shadow offset?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uibarbuttonitem

I'm trying to change the offset of the shadow behind the text in a `UIBarButtonItem`.

This is my code:

```
NSMutableDictionary *attributes = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[attributes setValue:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.30 alpha:1.0] forKey:UITextAttributeTextColor];
[attributes setValue:[UIColor whiteColor] forKey:UITextAttributeTextShadowColor];
[attributes setValue:[NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0.0, 0.0)] forKey:UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:attributes forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Changing the text color works. Changing the shadow color works. Changing the shadow offset doesn't seem to do anything.

Is something wrong with the way I'm doing this? I've also tried setting it directly, without the appearance proxy, but that didn't work either.

Comment: I'm going through the same issue now. Did you have any luck solving this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your code is correct though perhaps you expect something different from what it does.  If I paste it into a test app and change the offset values to 10.0, 10.0 the shadow offset is visible for me.  (iOS 5.0)

[image: Here's a clip taken from the simulator while running what you posted.]

Comment: I didn't measure exactly.  :-)  I've updated the answer to show what I'm seeing.

Comment: Ok, thanks for letting me know. I must be doing something wrong. Back to the drawing board...

Answer (score 0):

Your shadow UIOffset values are 0.0,0.0 which effectively causes no shadow. You will need to offset the shadow by at least 1 pixel in any direction. eg. this will give you a shadow to the bottom left side.

```
[NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(-1.0, 1.0)]
```